# Shipping cost is not including in paypal express checkout in wordpress woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, payment

I brought http://www.woothemes.com/products/paypal-express/ plugin for my wordpress site running woocommerce. But the shipping cost is not including during paypal express checkout.

I checked all setting in woocommerce shipping. I also checked other payment gateways they are including shipping cost

Can anyone please suggest how to include shipping cost in paypal express checkout for woocommerce.

Comment: Unfortunately, my experience with the Woo PayPal extensions left me wanting more...a lot more.  As such, I developed my own stand-alone extension, [PayPal for WooCommerce](http://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/), and I can assure you the shipping is passed correctly if you want to give it a try.  Oh yeah, it's free, too!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to edit the actual code in the plugi files woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express.php, Basically what I did was use the cart->get_cart_shipping_total() from the file. Unfortunately it comes formatted with html so I had to just explode out a couple things, I"ve included the code below.

```
$shipping = WC_PayPal_Express_Compatibility::WC()->cart->get_cart_shipping_total();
$shippingarray = explode(";", $shipping);
$shippingarray = explode("</span>", $shippingarray[1]);
$shippingamt = str_replace("_",".", $shippingarray[0]);
$nvpstr .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=" . $shippingamt;
```

Then you also have to edit the total amount line as well to:

```
$nvpstr .= "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT="     . number_format($order_total + $shippingamt, 2);
```